# How to check the methods and attributes of pyomo SolverFactory

Tags: pyomo

I am using the following code to work with pyomo model.

```
opt = pe.SolverFactory('gurobi')
res = opt.solve(model, tee=False,options=solver_opt)
walltime = res.solver.time
```

I tried several times to get the code snippet "**res.solver.time**" for obtaining the "**walltime**". Hence, I want to know where I can get the full list of methods and attributes in "opt". Then I can obtain other useful information. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime I'm poking around for a particular feature, I keep a terminal window open with `ipython` and use the code introspection feature to poke around (input 4 below).  Then you can use `?` or `??` (deep info, typically the source code) to get more info as in input 3 below.

Just type the command, '.', tab and poke around

This is the same stuff you would get from any IDE that supports introspection based code completion.  I like PyCharm for same reasons.

Realize of course that what is shown below are the methods associated with pyomo's `opt` object and **NOT** the solver (glpk in my case, gurobi in yours) options!

[image]

Comment: Thank you much for the useful information and demo. I just tried and found that res. works but res.solver does not work.

Comment: @WOOD In your context, `res` does not have a solver instance.  `res` is the result.  Try `type(res)`.  In your context `opt` is the solver.

Comment: @WOOD  Are you trying specifically to get the solve time out of the result or was that just an example?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That was just an example. I would like to know how I can get the full list of the attributes (e.g., time and others.) As you can see that I can get the solution time with res.solver.time. What should I do if I want to access other attributes in case I do not know if they exist?